# History search using pattern

Tags: linux, command-history

I was reading The complete reference: Linux and stumbled upon a text that I can't understand.

> With the command line editor, not only can you edit the current
>   command, you can also move to a previous event in the history list to
>   edit and execute it. The CTRL-P command then moves you up to the prior
>   event in the list. The CTRL-N command moves you down the list. The
>   ALT-< command moves you to the top of the list, and the ALT-> command
>   moves you to the bottom. You can even use a pattern to search for a
>   given event. The slash followed by a pattern searches backward in the
>   list, and the question mark followed by a pattern searches forward in
>   the list. The n command repeats the search.

It says "slash followed by a pattern searches backward in the list", but I don't know where to type it. For example if I wanted to search for something starting with `cp` so where do I write `/cp`? And how is this different from using <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>?

Comment: You'll have to be using the ZSh/KSh/KornSh I suspect. I believe they are Korn shell commands (Korn Shell led to ZSh or KSh).  The ^R we probably all use far more often is for BASH.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the text that you are reading is for something called the `readline` library, and while it is true that the shell command line does *use* that library for command line manipulation and editing, the shell configures it for its own use.

If you want to experiment with the `readline` library's `/` and `?` search commands, open a text file using the `less` browser. Your linux distribution may have already set `less` as its browser for `man` pages, so also try the search commands within a `man` page.

Comment: but how to use it to search history list?

Comment: See @guiverc's direct comment to your question. This feature is not implemented in `bash`.